# I can't able to add an array after declaring the array

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In this program

```
marks[0]="50";
```

is not working. It gives the error

```
[Error] invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
```

Here's the program:

```
int main()

{

    int marks[40];

    marks[0]={"50"};

    cout<<"Enter the marks: "<<endl;

    cin>>marks[1];

    cout<<marks[0];

    cout<<marks[1];

    return 0;



}
```

Comment: You try to put a string (`const char *) `in an `int[]`. Did you maybe just mean `marks[0]=50;`?

Comment: Your array takes integers, not character string literals.  And what is strange is that it takes more effort to type double quotes.  So you wasted effort in doing the wrong thing.

Comment: Expanding on the above comments: `"50"` is an array of characters, a null terminated string, not an `int`. They have different and incompatible types. Effectively this is trying to put the square block in the round hole.

Comment: Read about the concept of types in your favourite C++ book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do:

```
marks[0] = "50";
```

you are trying to assign a `char const *` to an `int`. Hence the error message.

The code you probably mean to write is:

```
marks[0] = 50;
```

which assigns an `int` to an `int`.